# Запуск EXE из приложения

Tags: c#, execute

Есть следующий код запуска приложения `Application2` из текущего `Application1`:

```
private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string file = Path.Combine("путь до папки приложения", "program.bin");
    if (!File.Exists(file))
        return;

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = file,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
}
```

На некоторых компьютерах либо постоянно, либо периодически, при попытке запуска приложения `Application2` из `Application1`, последнее закрывается с "непредвиденное завершение программы" или что-то в этом роде.

Вопрос: что не так в этом коде и есть ли более правильные способы
запуска другого приложения *.exe(bin)?

Comment: пока вы не поймете где конкретно проблема с приложением, что крашится, тут, как мне кажется, ответить нечего - код как код

Comment: В том и дело, что идей нет кроме как всё кругом помещать в try/catch.

Comment: ну так это нормально, у вас изначально должен был быть перехват исключений и логгирование, иначе как вы вообще понимаете что происходит в вашем приложении :)

Comment: Я просто не думал, что такая простая с виду конструкция требует "отлова" исключений, ведь всё необходимое проверяется до неё.

Comment: ну, по хорошему, у вас должен быть запускатель приложения как отдельный класс, который должен все проверить сам и запускать приложение уж точно не в UI потоке, при этом ловить все проблемы и как минимум логгировать их

Comment: @tym32167 отдельный класс или поток? Просто если использовать отдельный класс, то его методы всё равно будут обрабатываться в UI потоке. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Отдельный класс для того, чтобы ваша логика не была размазана по коду ([подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)). И этот отдельный класс по хорошему должен запускать приложение в отдельном потоке (например, в пуле потоков)

Comment: Выносить Process.Start в отдельный класс и фоновый поток, я думаю, перебор. А вот обрабатывать исключения на нем конечно же нужно. Ваша проверка Exists не дает 100% гарантии из-за "Race Conditions", да и вообще, все не перепроверишь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена после помещения кода запуска приложения в `try/catch` конструкцию. По крайней мере основное приложение больше не валится с непонятной ошибкой, а запускаемое вызывает системное исключение, которое после было отловлено через `sxstrace.exe` из журнала событий.

```
try
{
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = file,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        Process.Start(processStartInfo);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```